# How to maintain session in swagger editor

Tags: session, cookies, swagger, swagger-ui, suppress-warnings

I am using swagger for building API documentation. I am new to it. What I am doing is logging in first and the giving call to a list API. But as the session, cookies are not maintained, the list call is not getting executed. You need to first login to the application and then give call to the list. 
How can I do it in swagger editor http://editor.swagger.io/#/

Thankyou

Answer (score 2):

I just spent some time struggling with this same question and as far as I can tell the Swagger Editor will not make API calls with `xhr.withCredentials = true`, which means that your browser will not send cookies even if the server's CORS policy allows it. There's been some discussion of updating Swagger Editor to allow an option to do this (e.g., https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/issues/251), but it doesn't appear this has been done quite yet.

Your best option is probably to avoid the entire cross-origin security issue by hosting Swagger Editor on your own domain. This is one of the suggestions: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/blob/master/docs/cors.md#host-swagger-editor-in-your-own-domain. Just run it as if it was one of your own apps on your dev site.

Another suggestion is to just disable Chrome web security: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/blob/master/docs/cors.md#run-swagger-editor-in-a-browser-that-ignores-http-access-control. I haven't tried this but it may not work because Swagger Editor is still not setting the XHR request appropriately.

Finally, if you're familiar with docker, you can run a Swagger Editor docker instance and link everything up. This is complicated but I accomplished this by:

- running our backend inside a docker container
- running a Swagger Editor instance inside another docker container on the same network (https://hub.docker.com/r/swaggerapi/swagger-editor/)
- running an nginx reverse proxy server inside a third docker container such that any requests to, e.g., `http://localhost/dev/swagger-editor/` are proxy-forwarded to the swagger docker container and any requests to `http://localhost/api/` are proxy-forwarded to your backend. This way the browser only sees requests to `localhost` and everything works just fine.

But you need to be willing to get into docker and nginx reverse proxy configs before having a reasonable expectation you'll be successful with this. Otherwise this could be another rabbit hole. Good luck!

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. I have disabled the security for Chrome and its working for me. So lets see if I need so other way I will try out the next option.